# Building up html line by line using java HTMLEditorKit insertHTML

Tags: java

I am a total novice at java and programming, so to help me learn I am trying to build a trivial app that outputs some information to a logging window.

I am outputting to a JEditorPane.  But I wanted to include hyperlinks and possibly other html stuff, so am using an HTMLEditorKit on it and calling the insertHTML(...) method.

My issue seems to be (I think!) that I am trying to build the html code up line by line, which means leaving tags open until a later insertHTML closes them off.  But this doesn't seem to work.

For example, the following code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[30px][grow]"));
JEditorPane editorP = new JEditorPane();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorP); // put the editor pane into a scrollable pane
panel.add(scrollPane, "cell 0 1");
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
editorP.setContentType("text/html");
editorP.setEditable(false);
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) editorP.getDocument();
HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) editorP.getEditorKit();

try {
        kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<font face='calibri'>", 0, 0, null);
        kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "www.google.com", 0, 0, null);
        kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "</font>", 0, 0, null);
        kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<font face='calibri'>www.yahoo.com</font>", 0, 0, null);

        String debug = editorP.getText();
        System.out.println(debug);

} catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
```

results in the html:

```
  </head>
  <body>
www.google.com
<font face="calibri">www.yahoo.com</font>
  </body>
</html>
```

So it seems to me (I think!) that not closing off a tags fully in the insertHTML call results in them being dropped.

My question is: is there any way to do this line by line?  Or will I need to create my html code line by line in a string first and then pass that to insertHTML?

All help appreciated.